# How to debug freezing in tic-tac-toe in Python C Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In my game I have three problems: the sound plays with a delay after the victory and the program freezes when playing. The game does not work with the computer.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from time import strftime
import pygame


main_window = Tk()

CROSS_IMAGE = PhotoImage(file="image/close.png")
ZERO_IMAGE = PhotoImage(file="image/circle.png")

IMAGE_FOR_MOTION_CROSS = PhotoImage(file="image/close_little.png")
IMAGE_FOR_MOTION_ZERO = PhotoImage(file="image/circle_little.png")



Buttons = [[Button(), Button(), Button()], [Button(), Button(), Button()], [Button(), Button(), Button()]]

step = 0

game_with_computer = False

game_in_pairs = False

number_of_wins_of_crosses = 0

number_of_wins_of_zero = 0

image_for_motion_label = Label()

game_with_computer_button = Label()

game_in_pairs_button = Label()

score_label = Label()

restart_button = Button()


def restart_game():
    global Buttons
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            Buttons[i][j]["text"] = ""
            Buttons[i][j].configure(state='normal', image="")

    restart_button.configure(background="#fefcfa")

    global step
    step = 0

    global image_for_motion_label
    image_for_motion_label.config(image='')


def start_game_with_computer():
    restart_game()

    game_with_computer_button.configure(background="#f8d3d3")
    game_in_pairs_button.configure(background="#fefcfa")

    global game_with_computer
    game_with_computer = True

    global game_in_pairs
    game_in_pairs = False


def start_game_with_pair():
    restart_game()

    game_in_pairs_button.configure(background="#f8d3d3")
    game_with_computer_button.configure(background="#fefcfa")

    global game_with_computer
    game_with_computer = False

    global game_in_pairs
    game_in_pairs = True


def create_main_window():
    global main_window
    main_window.title("Крестики-нолики")
    main_window.geometry("850x450")
    main_window.resizable(False, False)
    image_icon = PhotoImage(file="image/logo.png")
    main_window.iconphoto(False, image_icon)

    main_window.image = PhotoImage(file="image/bg.png")
    bg_label = ttk.Label(image=main_window.image)
    bg_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

    time_label = Label(anchor="center", font=("Bahnschrift", 11), background="#fefcfa")
    time_label.place(width=95, height=20, relx=0.014, rely=0.02)

    def time_display():
        string = strftime('%H : %M : %S')
        time_label.config(text=string)
        time_label.after(1000, time_display)

    time_display()

    dividing_line = ttk.Label(background="#f8d3d3")
    dividing_line.place(width=10, height=450, x=390, y=0)

    image_computer = PhotoImage(file="image/computer.png")
    image_computer_label = ttk.Label(image=image_computer, background="#fefcfa")
    image_computer_label.place(width=35, height=35, x=8, y=49)

    global game_with_computer_button
    game_with_computer_button = Button(
        text="Игра с компьютером",
        font=("Bahnschrift", 10),
        background="#fefcfa",
        command=start_game_with_computer
    )
    game_with_computer_button.place(width=150, height=30, x=46, y=50)

    image_user = PhotoImage(file="image/user.png")
    image_game_user = Label(image=image_user, background="#fefcfa")
    image_game_user.place(width=35, height=35, x=8, y=100)

    global game_in_pairs_button
    game_in_pairs_button = Button(
        text="Игра в паре",
        font=("Bahnschrift", 10),
        background="#fefcfa",
        command=start_game_with_pair
    )
    game_in_pairs_button.place(width=150, height=30, x=46, y=100)

    motion_label = ttk.Label(text="Ходит:", background="#fefcfa", font=("Bahnschrift", 12))
    motion_label.place(width=73, height=30, x=410, y=5)

    global image_for_motion_label
    image_for_motion_label = ttk.Label(background="#fefcfa")
    image_for_motion_label.place(width=35, height=35, x=465, y=4)

    global restart_button
    restart_button = Button(font=("Bahnschrift", 12), background="#fefcfa", text="Рестарт", command=restart_game)
    restart_button.place(width=73, height=30, x=310, y=405)

    global score_label
    score_label = ttk.Label(anchor="center", font=("Bahnschrift", 30), background="#fefcfa", text="0 : 0")
    score_label.place(width=100, height=50, x=150, y=230)

    cross_image_for_score = PhotoImage(file="image/close_score.png")
    zero_image_for_score = PhotoImage(file="image/circle_score.png")

    label_cross_image_for_score = Label(background="#fefcfa", image=cross_image_for_score)
    label_cross_image_for_score.place(width=32, height=32, x=110, y=240)
    label_zero_image_for_score = Label(background="#fefcfa", image=zero_image_for_score)
    label_zero_image_for_score.place(width=32, height=32, x=255, y=240)


def algorithm_game_with_easy_computer():
    is_free = False
    while is_free:
        column = random.randint(0, 2)
        row = random.randint(0, 2)
        if Buttons[column][row]["text"] == "":
            Buttons[column][row]["text"] = "o"
            Buttons[column][row].configure(image=ZERO_IMAGE, state='disabled')
            detect_if_game_is_over_and_animate_result_line()
            return


def disable_all_buttons():
    global Buttons
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            Buttons[i][j].configure(state='disabled')


def detect_if_game_is_over_and_animate_result_line():
    global Buttons
    global restart_button

    def increase_counter(sing):
        global number_of_wins_of_crosses
        global number_of_wins_of_zero
        if sing == "x":
            number_of_wins_of_crosses += 1
            restart_button.configure(background="#FF9995")
        else:
            number_of_wins_of_zero += 1
            restart_button.configure(background="#92BBD6")

    def change_buttons_state(btn1, btn2, btn3):
        btn1.configure(state="normal")
        btn2.configure(state="normal")
        btn3.configure(state="normal")

    # check columns
    for i in range(3):
        if (Buttons[i][0]["text"] == Buttons[i][1]["text"]) \
           and (Buttons[i][0]["text"] == Buttons[i][2]["text"]) \
           and (Buttons[i][0]["text"] != ""):
            disable_all_buttons()
            # animate result line
            change_buttons_state(Buttons[i][0], Buttons[i][1], Buttons[i][2])
            increase_counter(Buttons[i][0]["text"])
            return True

        # check rows
    for i in range(3):
        if (Buttons[0][i]["text"] == Buttons[1][i]["text"]) \
           and (Buttons[0][i]["text"] == Buttons[2][i]["text"]) \
           and (Buttons[0][i]["text"] != ""):
            disable_all_buttons()
            # animate result line
            change_buttons_state(Buttons[0][i], Buttons[1][i], Buttons[2][i])
            increase_counter(Buttons[0][i]["text"])
            return True

            # check first diagonal
    if (Buttons[0][0]["text"] == Buttons[1][1]["text"]) \
        and (Buttons[0][0]["text"] == Buttons[2][2]["text"]) \
            and (Buttons[0][0]["text"] != ""):
        disable_all_buttons()
        # animate result line
        change_buttons_state(Buttons[0][0], Buttons[1][1], Buttons[2][2])
        increase_counter(Buttons[0][0]["text"])
        return True

        # check second diagonal
    if (Buttons[2][0]["text"] == Buttons[1][1]["text"]) \
        and (Buttons[2][0]["text"] == Buttons[0][2]["text"]) \
            and (Buttons[2][0]["text"] != ""):
        disable_all_buttons()
        # animate result line
        change_buttons_state(Buttons[2][0], Buttons[1][1], Buttons[0][2])
        increase_counter(Buttons[2][0]["text"])
        return True

    return False


def play_win_audio():
    def play_audio(file_path):
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(file_path)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    sound_file = r"sounds/win.mp3"
    play_audio(sound_file)

    # Поддерживаем проигрывание в течение 5 секунд
    pygame.time.delay(1000)
    pygame.mixer.quit()


def event_button_click(event):
    # sound_file = "c:\win.wav"
    global number_of_wins_of_crosses
    global number_of_wins_of_zero
    global game_with_computer
    global game_in_pairs
    global step


    button = event.widget
    if button["text"] != "":
        return

    if detect_if_game_is_over_and_animate_result_line():
        return

    # отрисовать новый крестик или нолик на нажатой кнопке
    step += 1
    if game_in_pairs:
        if step % 2 != 0:
            button.configure(image=CROSS_IMAGE, state='disabled')
            button["text"] = "x"
            image_for_motion_label.configure(image=IMAGE_FOR_MOTION_ZERO)
        else:
            button.configure(image=ZERO_IMAGE, state='disabled')
            button["text"] = "o"
            image_for_motion_label.configure(image=IMAGE_FOR_MOTION_CROSS)

    if game_with_computer:
        if step % 2 != 0:
            button.configure(image=CROSS_IMAGE, state='disabled')
            button["text"] = "x"
            image_for_motion_label.configure(image=IMAGE_FOR_MOTION_ZERO)
        else:
            algorithm_game_with_easy_computer()
            image_for_motion_label.configure(image=IMAGE_FOR_MOTION_CROSS)

    if step == 9:
        showinfo(title="Ничья", message=f"Игра окончена. Победила дружба")
        restart_game()

    # проверить, не привел ли последний ход к выигрышу текущего игрока
    if step >= 5 and detect_if_game_is_over_and_animate_result_line():
        score_label['text'] = f"{number_of_wins_of_crosses} : {number_of_wins_of_zero}"
        play_win_audio()


def start_game():
    global number_of_wins_of_crosses
    number_of_wins_of_crosses = 0

    global number_of_wins_of_zero
    number_of_wins_of_zero = 0

    global game_with_computer
    game_with_computer = False

    global game_in_pairs
    game_in_pairs = False

    global step
    step = 0

    global Buttons

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            Buttons[i][j] = Button(relief="ridge", background="#fefcfa", borderwidth=0, state='disabled')
            Buttons[i][j].bind("<Button-1>", event_button_click)
            Buttons[i][j].place(width=95, height=95, x=465 + (100 * i), y=84 + (100 * j))

    disable_all_buttons()


def draw_playing_field():
    field_label_horizont_1 = ttk.Label(background='black')
    field_label_horizont_1.place(width=300, height=4, x=462, y=180)

    field_label_horizon_2 = ttk.Label(background='black')
    field_label_horizon_2.place(width=300, height=4, x=462, y=280)

    field_label_vertically_1 = ttk.Label(background='black')
    field_label_vertically_1.place(width=4, height=300, x=560, y=80)

    field_label_vertically_2 = ttk.Label(background='black')
    field_label_vertically_2.place(width=4, height=300, x=660, y=80)


def handle_window_closure():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Выход", "Вы уверены, что хотите выйти?"):
        main_window.destroy()


def main():
    main_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", handle_window_closure)

    create_main_window()
    draw_playing_field()
    start_game()

    main_window.mainloop()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And another problem: images are not visible:
[There should be images here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJGKQ.png)

I've tried different libraries, different audio file formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick look I see a few issues in your code that might be causing the problems you mentioned.

Sound delay issue, the `pygame.time.delay(1000)` line after playing the audio in the play_win_audio function might be causing your issue. Instead, you can use the `pygame.mixer.music.get_length()` function to get the length of the audio file and delay accordingly, like this `pygame.time.delay(int(pygame.mixer.music.get_length()) * 1000)`

Freezing issue, the `algorithm_game_with_easy_computer()` function has an issue where is_free is initialized as False, which leads to an infinite loop. You should change it to True to enter the loop `is_free = True`.

Game with computer issue, I'm not sure what the problem could be there not without more information anyway so I'm sorry. Only thing I can think of is to check are if the computer has all the libraries needed installed.

In terms of you missing images some things to check is that the paths to your image files are correct. Make sure the image files are in the correct directory. The paths should be relative to the script file or you can use an absolute path.